# E: Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-good' has no installation candidate

Tags: 18.04

i am using Ubuntu 18.04 and i required to install
gst-plugins-good-0.10.0 but while installing with command

```
$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
```

getting error as

```
E: Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-good' has no installation candidate
```

please help me with any other solution to install gst-plugins-good-0.10.0 successfully.

thank in advance

Comment: Hello. Please read your question and edit it so that it makes more sense. How does installing this one file give you a make file. As well as confusing it needs more info.

Comment: hi David thank for response ,i have edited my question yes there was typo becoz i was finding solution from different resources anyhow that doesn't wok for me. my goal is to install gstreamer0.10-plugins-good.

Answer (score 0):

Search on github for the gstreamer package that suits your distro or flavour.
Then download the package file/s.
Extract the file using `sudo dpkg-deb -xv <filename>.deb /home/Public`
then `cd Public`
then `sudo apt-get install ./<filename>.deb`

Comment: thank for response i followed your steps but getting error as unable to locate package libgstreamer

Comment: OK I'll edit the answer for the old-skool approach (gstreamer is pretty old).